# Shortcut To Initialize a Map in Clojure

Tags: clojure, hashmap

So in ES6, I can do something like this:

```
let x=1 y=1 z=1
let o = {x, y,z}
console.log(o.x)  //prints 1
```

I don't see any built in way to do something like this in clojure.  Can one do any better than this to return a map from a function that takes a number of arguments?

```
(defn foo
  [x y z]
  {:x x :y y :z z})

(pprint (get  ( foo 1 2 3) :x)) ;prints 1
```

Comment: Is the big difference that you want to auto-generate keywordized map keys from the function argument names?

Comment: Yes,that's the difference.

Comment: I reread your question, and realized that I misinterpreted what you were trying to do. No, there isn't a built in way to automatically generate keys based on the names of the variables that are holding the data given to a literal. Tying key names to the names of the variables that originally held the data seems like it would be brittle anyways though. If you wanted to change some local naming to improve clarity, you'd have to change everything that references the keys of the map as well.

Comment: I suppose. Perhaps I am not thinking in a lisp like fashion yet!  It seems like a convenient thing to do, and clojure as some of the capabilities when destructuring using :keys. Your answer is still helpful.

Comment: I think the use case may be relevant here. Most of the time I just use records to hold associative data, unless I need it for more "dynamic" purposes (counting letter frequencies in a String, where the keys used will obviously vary). Ya, it is declaring a type when you use a record, but the explicitness of the declaration might prevent confusion down the road. If you're using a map with consistent keys everywhere, having an explicit declaration outlining the keys used may prove beneficial. Not the mention the speed benefits of using a record, which may or not be relevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a dozen reasons why doing this isn't a good idea, but the cool thing about a lisp is that you can do what you want, and if the language doesn't do what you want, you can extend it.

Here's a simple macro

```
(defmacro infer-map [& args]
  {:pre [(every? symbol? args)]}
  `(hash-map
     ~@(interleave
         (map (comp keyword name) args)
         args)))
```

And the usage:

```
(let [x 1 y 2 z 3]
  (infer-map x y z))
=> {:y 2, :z 3, :x 1}
```

Comment: Any reason not to simplify this to:
`(zipmap (map (comp keyword name) args) args)`

Comment: It's a macro, so you have to use syntax quoting and it can't be done as a function because you need the names of the symbols involved (not their values). Also, pre-interleaving the keys and values will be much more efficient. For small maps he cost of creating the maps will be 1-2 allocations. With zipmap you have the cost of walking some seqs as well as all the intermediate immutable structures as you ad the items one at a time.

Comment: It sure seems to work, however.

`(defmacro identity-map [& args]
  {:pre [(every? symbol? args)]}
  (zipmap (map (comp keyword name) args) args))`


> (let [a 1 b [2 3] c "4"] (identity-map a b c))

{:a 1, :b [2 3], :c "4"}

> (let [a 1 b [2 3] c "4"] (macroexpand '(identity-map a b c)))

{:a a, :b b, :c c}

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `vals->context` and `with-context` [in the Tupelo Clojure library](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo).  The unit tests show this feature in action:

```
(dotest
  (let [ctx     (let [a 1
                      b 2
                      c 3
                      d 4
                      e 5]
                  (vals->context a b c d e)) ]
    (is= ctx {:a 1 :b 2 :c 3 :d 4 :e 5})

    (let [{:keys [a b c d e]} ctx]
      (is= [a b c d e] [1 2 3 4 5]))

    (with-context ctx [a b c d e]
      (is= [a b c d e] [1 2 3 4 5])
      (is= 15 (+ a b c d e)))
    (with-context ctx [b a d c e] ; order doesn't matter
      (is= [a b c d e] [1 2 3 4 5])
      (is= 15 (+ a b c d e)))

    (throws?
      (with-context ctx [x y z]
        (println "shouldn't ever get here")))))
```